# Moving back and forth between pages doesn't trigger alert more than once

Tags: vue.js, dom, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a blog (`website.com`), with a page for posts (`website.com/post?id=...`).

What I want, is whenever I go to post page, to trigger JS's alert.

This is the code for post page:

```
export default {
  name: 'PagePost',
  data() {
    alert(1)
  ...
```

The problem is that if I go post page its trigger an alert, **but** if I go to another post it doesn't alert again, (it does only when I refresh the page).
From what I cloud understand, Vue save the page in the DOM, so it doesn't run this again (only when refreshing the page).

How can I re-trigger alert when the user go back and forth between pages?

P.S. what I'm trying to accomplish is when a user go between pages, to reload the post and the comments (without needing to refresh the page), but I tried to make the problem easier with trigger.

P.S. #2 I prefer to run the alert in the `mounted()` function, because it's loading faster than `data()`.

Comment: Have you tried to put your alert into the "updated" vue lifecycle hook? As far as I remember, it will be called whenever the data of your DOM is changed.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using vue router. Take a look at `beforeEnter` method. You need define it in post route and trigger alert there.